# How to add value to a field from another lookup field?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a custom entity `Partnership` in which I have one lookup field contacts.
now I want to add the name field value of the `partnership` from `contact` fullname in time of creation of `Partnership`.

is it possible with the help of pre-existing configuration settings,(without plugin or web resource)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to click the "New Partnership" button in the CRM ribbon, then select a contact, and have the name of the contact, be used to populate another field on the form, you will have to use JavaScript.  There is no configurable way of doing it.

If you'd like the value to be populated before it is saved in the CRM database, you could use JavaScript, or a custom Plugin.  If you'd like the value to be updated after the record is created, you could use a workflow.

You'll have to use one of those three methods to populate the field.  The real question I have though, is why are you bothering to populate the field in the first place?  You can add the full Contact name to any view, so I don't see a real big reason to include it.

Answer (score 3):

Without using a plug-in or web resource you have a couple options.

1- You can configure the mappings between the 2 entities by going to the Entity (contact) -> Relationship -> Mappings -> and add a new mapping there.  For this to work though, you will need to create the child record from the subgrid of the contact, and if the contact changes it won't update the values.  So it may or may not be an ideal solution for you.

[image]

2- You can create a workflow rule that runs on create and/or update of the Partnership record that pulls the value from the parent contact onto the partnership record.  The downside of this is that workflows are async so you won't see the update for a few seconds and refresh the Partner record.

Hope this helps.